# JPasswordField text color over written by paintcomponent

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

So I made my custom JPasswordField component and in it I change the background color to a color with alpha

```
this.setBackground( new Color(29, 29, 29, 150) );
this.setOpaque(false);
```

And I also make the button round so I need to use this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(getBackground());
    g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), radius, radius);
}
```

The problem is my text when i type is almost unreadable [image: Field] It requires me to highlight it so i can see it.

This is my foreground color:

```
this.setForeground(new Color(250,250,250, 250));
```

I changed the color a bit since the screenshot but i still have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic logic is reversed.

First you invoke `super.paintComponent()` which will paint the text.

Then you invoke `fillRoundRect(...)` which will paint over top of the text.

The logic should be reversed:

1. paint the background
2. invoke super.paintComponent(...)